# How do I download a torrent using python and Torrent reactor API?

Tags: python

```
http://www.torrentreactor.to/torrents_search_rss.php
```

How do I make the API call and then once I have the XML response , I want to auto select a single file with the highest no. of seeds and peers and download it automatically . How do I do it in python ?

Note: I tried coding it but it gave me a response saying `error:invalid order creation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just got your query string wrong: this

> http://www.torrentreactor.to/torrents_search_rss.php?q=portal&o=ul&d=desc

works fine to me. Once downloaded, parse it with the help of the [feedparser](http://feedparser.org/) library and (assuming you'll call your feed object `torrents`) get the first url this way: `torrent.links[1].rel`.

To save the torrent file, once you got the url, use urllib2:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
torrent = opener.open(url)
savefile = open(torrent_name, "wb")
savefile.write(torrent)
savefile.close()
```

You will have to import: webbrowser, urllib, os.

Comment: How to replace a portal with a variable name that changes with every function call ? Do I have to urlencode it?

Comment: nice question: portal is in fact a wonderful game, and should not be downloaded illegally. anyway: you have to urlencode it. to make it change every time: put the code in a function that accepts one argument; make a list of titles; make a ´for item in list´ loop to pass a different argument to the function.

Comment: nice ^^ if it helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting this answer - thanks ^^

Comment: though It didnt help in "how to download " part . I mean I get the url and then I have call that same url link again . Need to figure out how to download that particular torrent

Comment: uh, sorry. I thought you knew that already. updating the code soon - here you go.

Answer (score 0):

For movie downloading purposes u can use a nice library called

> **pyYify**

`pip install pyYify`

which does most of the work of handling the magnet link and starting the downloads for you and stuff . Here is the github link for the library . 
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyYify

It also has torrent search feature for movies along with quality controls and rating selections u can use in your code .

The search_string for the movie can be 'Movie Title,IMDb Code, Actor Name, Director Name'. quality = 'All' , '720p' , '1080p' , '3D'.

Since Yify is one of most reliable sources to get the movies it works pretty well for all movies i have tested (which is a lot )

Comment: Can you please provide an example of python script